# Deleting a row from database and gridview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, gridview

I want to delete a row from gridview and database - I write some code but this code just delete the first row of my gridview!
Please help me. I used Entity Framework and wpf C#.

```
using (AccountingEntities cntx = new AccountingEntities())
{
   Producer item = this.grdProducers.SelectedItem as Producer;
   cntx.DeleteObject(cntx.Producers.First(x => x.ID == item.ID));
   cntx.SaveChanges();
   dataPager.Source = cntx.Producers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any requirement like making first item as selected after deleting the selected item...?

Comment: after deleting an item by default first item selected. i think this is the default behavior of the gridview.

Comment: You might consider that it is a LINQ+ problem, because the key code is
*cntx.DeleteObject(cntx.Producers.First(x => x.ID == item.ID)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution: when i open the dialog for confirming the delete action, selected item changed. **i should select the entityId before opening the dialog**. the below code show how to do this:

```
            int unitTypeId = (this.grdUnitTypes.SelectedItem as UnitType).ID;
            ConfirmWindowResult result = Helpers.ShowConfirm(this, SR.GlobalMessages.AreYouSureToDelete, SR.GlobalMessages.Warning);
            if (result == ConfirmWindowResult.Yes)
            {
                using (AccountingEntities cntx = new AccountingEntities())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cntx.UnitTypes.DeleteObject(cntx.UnitTypes.First(x => x.ID == unitTypeId));
                        cntx.SaveChanges();
                        dataPager.Source = cntx.UnitTypes.ToList();
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cntx.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should simple try:

```
cntx.DeleteObject(cntx.Producers.where(x => x.ID == item.ID));

// if you get my .where() code to return the entity's index you'll should be fine
```

This should invoke the appropiate lambda/linq.
Since you use "`where`" the expression is applied to every "Producer"-Entity `x` matching `item.ID`

UPDATE:

From MSDN:

> Deletes the record at the specified index from the data source.

```
DeleteObject(int rowIndex)
```

Well this explains a lot. Because this means, that your simply passing in the wrong argument.
You need to loop through the whole Grid with a foreach or for and delete each entity with deleteObject and check before whether the object's id matches item.ID.

I am sure this would be easier by using Lambda/LINQ but I currently have no idea how this could be done otherwise.

I also found this quite interesting, you have to scroll down to "delete", the example is for a database, but still uses the grid as buffer so it should be the similiar problem.

http://www.asp.net-crawler.com/articles/LINQ/Insert-retrieve-update-delete-through-gridview-using-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- No this is not work. no error but the entity dont delete! i realy tired.

Comment: @mze666 that is really strange, since the logic behind the code should exactly do what you want to have as result.